# Calling actors by name and getting coordinates of them

Tags: libgdx

Is there anyway to call the actors by name? For example i've actors named act1 to act35 on stage. I want to get the actors x,y by name. Is this possible in libgdx?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done via `stage.getRoot().findActor(name)`.